# The property 'PreserveTimestamp' cannot be found on this object when using WinSCP .NET assembly

Tags: powershell, sftp, winscp, winscp-net

I'm getting this error:

```
The property 'PreserveTimestamp' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set.
At path\OSBU_Broker_Extract02.ps1:14 
char:3
+   $session.PreserveTimestamp = $False
+   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyAssignmentException
```

```
If the problem persists, turn off setting permissions or preserving timestamp. Alternatively you can turn on 'Ignore 
permission errors' option.
The server does not support the operation.
```

I'm not sure where I should set my variable, please see my code below:

```
# Load WinSCP .NET assembly
Add-Type -Path "WinSCPnet.dll"

# Setup session options
$sessionOptions = New-Object WinSCP.SessionOptions -Property @{
    Protocol = [WinSCP.Protocol]::Sftp
    HostName = "[server IP]"
    UserName = "[username]"
    Password = ""
    SshHostKeyFingerprint = "ssh-rsa 1024 ...="
}

$session = New-Object WinSCP.Session
$session.PreserveTimestamp = $False

try
{
    # Connect
    $session.Open($sessionOptions)

    # Upload
    $session.PutFiles("filename.xlsx", "/destination/").Check()
}
finally
{
    # Disconnect, clean up
    $session.Dispose()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`PreserveTimestamp` is a property of the `TransferOptions` class](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_transferoptions#preservetimestamp), not `Session`.

A `TransferOptions` instance should be passed as a fourth argument of the [`Session.PutFiles`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_session_putfiles):

```
# Set up transfer options
$transferOptions = New-Object WinSCP.TransferOptions -Property @{
    PreserveTimestamp = $False
}

# Transfer files
$session.PutFiles("filename.xlsx", "/destination/", $False, $transferOptions).Check()
```

---

Also, in general, the paths should be absolute (not just `filename.xlsx`).